# Drop Down Menu Stacking

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have a custom css drop down menu and it works fine except I realized that writing this menu out across all the html pages on this website will become tedious if I should update with a new section to the website and need to add on a new tier to the menu, I would end up with a billion htmls to update one simple line of code.

I was wondering, is there a way to write this menu once (on the main page) and call on it on all my other htmls?

I experimented a bit with Objects, Iframe, to call on the dropdown menu written on a separate html file and such but when the menu expands you get scroll bars and both methods seem to embed into the page. I want the contents of the page to be behind the drop down menu just as it standardly looks right now.

The following is my unedited page:

http://www.blue-cicada.net/trivial/index.html

And this is my test:

http://www.blue-cicada.net/trivial/test/

Not looking so good there, my top image is obscured, the submenus wont fly out completely etc, how to fix?

Im really new to this stuff so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something server side really,  back in the day this would have been http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes, depending on who is hosting your site it may even still be, though that's fairly unlikely.  Chances are you have some provision from your webhost to do something server side, ie  PHP Includes say.

If not you could look at doing JavaScript client side includes but its crufty,

If you're really just hand editing you html files and have no access to any server side technologies well,  you can always just have a text editor that can search and replace across multiple files

### UPDATE

Given your comments I would just download something like Notepad++ and read the Bulk Find and Replace here 'http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/notepadpp-tricks.html'.  Basically you can have a test page you use for figuring out 'what you want to do' and then use the global find and replace to update all of the 'current' versions of the header/menu/whatever to you new version.

Backup all you files first!

Comment: Yeah I hand edit all my html files on notepad, already this website I cound t47 html files, it would be a pain to notepad all of those one by one if I happen to update one of the submenus. :\

Im able to do some things like htaccess but I wouldn't have the first clue on how to go about doing all that.

Comment: Thanks I tried Notepad++ but found it too confusing. If it would simply select and replace a range of lines across all my html files I'd be happy but it was way too complicated. I really dont get why they complicate stuff. All I need is line 27-100 to select and replace but do it across all my open html docs :(

Answer (score 0):

Write it in a page called `A.html.`

On every page where you want to put it, use an `<iframe src="A.html">`

Make sure you remove the borders of the `<iframe>`, and also the scrollbars and make it look natural

Comment: http://www.blue-cicada.net/trivial/test/

Doesn't look right, it chops off the menu when you drop down.

Comment: Which menu are you talking about?

Comment: The only menu on the page? At the top